# Como instalar e configurar a biblioteca Boost C++ no Windows?

Tags: c++, windows-10, boost

Há algum tempo tenho me empenhado bastante para aprender C e C++, acredito que já sei o suficiente para escrever uma aplicação um pouco mais complexa, utilizando *Sockets* e *Threads*.

Pesquisando um pouco, descobri o framework **Boost C++ Libraries**, e por mais que eu tenha tentando, não conseguir configurá-lo.
Estou usando *Code::Blocks* e gostaria simplesmente de incluir os *headers* e sair usando os recursos do *Boost*, no entanto sempre é mostrado algum erro de (referência não definida boost:system::generic_category etc...).
Nas configurações de *build* já indiquei o diretório de *Libs* e de *Includes*, ainda sim, o erro persiste.

Tentei incluir `-lboost_system` e diz `"cannot find -lboost_system"`.
Obs, os passos de instalação eu segui os disponíveis por aí na internet e também da documentação oficial.
Alguém que já tenha conseguido configurar e usar *boost* com sucesso, dê-me uma luz?

Comment: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/BoostWindowsQuickRef

Comment: Aqui tem um passo a passo, veja se te ajuda. [https://gist.github.com/sim642/29caef3cc8afaa273ce6](https://gist.github.com/sim642/29caef3cc8afaa273ce6)
Você está usando MingW ou VSC++?

Comment: Segue esse guia [aqui](https://gist.github.com/sim642/29caef3cc8afaa273ce6), bem explicativo.

Comment: Bom dia, segue link com ajuda para o que precisa: [Link para instalação](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#id29)

Answer (score -3):

Para instalar e configurar a biblioteca Boost C++ no Windows, você pode seguir as instruções em Vcpkg1. Vcpkg é um gerenciador de pacotes C++ para Windows que permite instalar facilmente bibliotecas C++ de código aberto em seu sistema1. Para instalar a biblioteca Boost.Test dinâmica ou estática, execute “vcpkg install boost-test” no prompt de comando1. Em seguida, execute “vcpkg integrate install” para configurar o Visual Studio com a biblioteca e incluir caminhos para os cabeçalhos e os binários do Boost1. Espero que isso ajude!